# PHPMailer: duplicate email

Tags: phpmailer

I am using OPHPMailer to send a form in the meantime, when sending this image appears and the email is duplicated in my inbox.
I'm using Yahoo Mail

[PHP send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu1hg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code and the log as text and not as an image.

Comment: I will include it in the answer to my question.

Comment: +1 to @ewong's comment, it would be easier to understand the question if we could see what code caused duplicate emails. Does the code in the answer solve the problem? If so, where exactly was the problem?

Comment: The code below is what I'm using and it's causing the two errors: the duplicate of emails and the "error" in sending, as shown in the image

Comment: I recommend reading [the PHPMailer docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Diagnosing-email-sending-twice-(or-more)). Your screen shots show only a single message being sent, so it's most likely that your script is being called twice. It's up to you to find out what's doing that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

require_once('src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('src/SMTP.php');
require_once('src/Exception.php');
 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : 'Não informado';
$telefone = isset($_POST['telefone']) ? $_POST['telefone'] : 'Não informado';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'Não informado';
$assunto = isset($_POST['assunto']) ? $_POST['assunto'] : 'Não informado';
$mensagem = isset($_POST['mensagem']) ? $_POST['mensagem'] : 'Não informado';
$data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

if($email && $mensagem ) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = 'Email hidden for security';
    $mail->Password = 'Password hidden for security';

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->setFrom('Email hidden for security');
    $mail->addAddress('Email hidden for security');
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = "Nome: {$nome}<br>
                Telefone: {$telefone}<br>
                Email: {$email}<br>
                Mensagem: {$mensagem}<br>
                Data/hora: {$data}";
    if($mail->send()) {
        echo 'Email enviado com sucesso';
    } else {
        echo 'Email nao enviado';
        }
}
```

[image: Screen 2]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add this information to your question by editing it, then delete this answer. Answers are for other people to answer your questions!

Comment: I just changed the line:
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1
for
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0